# Delphi Update record´s Insert if necessary from Adotable 2 into AdoTable 1

Tags: delphi, datatable

```
Filter AdoQuery_1 Record
SQL.Add('SELECT * from    Med');
                  SQL.Add('Where Cliente Like ''%'+Edit1.text );
and

update AdoQuery_1 from AdoQuery_2  (master)
 Update record´s of Table1 from Table2 (chield)
    Update record´s of Table3 from Table4 (chield)
```

is there a faster way to update the selected record and do the same for the child table records?

Answer (score 0):

1. Best - more simple and more fast - will be to do that in SQL. Depending on your DBMS, you can create a stored procedure, doing all these 3 steps.
2. I am not sure, but in AdoQuery_1 you are using LIKE to select a single client or few clients ? If few, then (1) approach will really speedup updates.

Comment: I use .mdb so i´m limited ( Update record´s of Table1 from Table2 (chield) ) this encounter a error because i have in each table a Autoencrente field!!!! SQL.Add('Where Cliente Like ''%'+Edit1.text ); Only select´s a record the reference where to inserte the record.
thank´s

Comment: A single record in the master in the datail normaly i nead to seach some fields.

Thanks